# Exiting the method from a ternary operator

Tags: java, return, conditional-operator

So somewhere in one of my methods, I'm calling another method called `foo()` and want to use ternary operator to write a short-hand if statement based on what `foo()`returns. Here's the `foo()` method:

```
public boolean foo(String s){
  if (!s.contentEquals("")){
    System.out.println(s);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The case in which I want to use the ternary operator with the return value of `foo()` looks like this:

```
(...)
boolean bool = foo("abc") ? null : return;
(...)
```

I basically want the method to do nothing and keep going if `foo()` returns true, and exit out if it returns false.

Is there a way to achieve this using the ternary operator?

Comment: Just use `if/else`.

Comment: IMO ick (even if it worked). `if (!foo("abc")) return;` and don't make people think so much.

Comment: @DaveNewton Whats "IMO ick"?

Comment: @Unmitigated I know I can use if/else, I'm wondering if I can do it with the ternary operator. Hence the question

Comment: @DaveNewton that's a nice short-hand way to write it. I might use this!

Comment: @LucasB.Bahadir No, you cannot do it with the ternary operator.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS IMO = "In My Opinion". "Ick" is shorthand for "gross", "ugly", "hard to read", "Noooooo" :)

Comment: I'm with Dave on this, but there might be a hackilicous way: What does the rest of your method look like? Is it smallish?

Comment: btw, your `foo` method should just be `return !s.contentEquals("");` or even better deleted and replaced with `!s.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator ("the operator with three operands" is `a silly way to describe it) is [an operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), and all three of its operands need to be expressions.

"return" is not an expression, it is [a statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17), and therefore can't be used where an expression is needed.

Furthermore, the result of an expression involving the conditional operator is itself an expression, and cannot be used where a statement is needed.

Expressions and statements are different entities in Java.